# Accessing variable in ViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, view, controller

Hello I am working on a web view based application, I have a WebController within that I have a variable which holds the current URL.

I have recently added code to launch a view, this works fine, this view also holds another web view, this web view works fine if I load a site into it such as this:

```
[[mywebview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
               [@"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" stringByAppendingString:@"test"]]]];
```

However I am trying to access the variable which holds the current URL like this:

```
 [[mywebview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
               [@"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" stringByAppendingString:currentURL]]]];
```

However when doing this by linking to the WebController the currentURL seems to equal nothing, however this works perfectly fine when doing it from the first responder (except of course the view no longer shows)

My question is how can I get my currentURL variable working when linked from the WebController?

I am relatively new to cocoa so I am sorry if this is easy question!

**EDIT: added from comments**

In the method `initWithWindowController` `currentURL` is set to `@""`, and in `dealloc` to `nil`. The currentURL comes from the other web view see here:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    if (frame != [self.webView mainFrame]) 
        return; 
    self.currentUrl = [[[[frame provisionalDataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
    [self retain]; 
}
```

I am declaring currentURL in the WebController.h

```
@interface WebController : NSObject <DOMEventListener>
 { 
   IBOutlet NSString *currentURL; 
 } 
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet NSString *currentURL; 
@end
```

I am trying to use the currentURL in the WebController.m in the DisplayInView function.

```
-(IBAction) DisplayInView:(id) sender 
{      
if ([siteview isInFullScreenMode])           
 {                
  [siteview exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:nil];           
 }      
else           
 {                
  [[mywebview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:                [@"google.com/search?hl=en&q="stringByAppendingString:currentURL]]]];                siteview enterFullScreenMode:[[siteview window] screen] withOptions:nil];           
 } 
} 
@synthesize siteview; 
@end
```

Comment: Can you show where you set the currentURL var?

Comment: To answer this question we need to know how you declare 'currentURL' and how you assign it a value.

Comment: It's set to @"" in the initWithWindowController

in dealloc: currentURL=nil;

The currentURL comes from the other web view see here:

- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    if (frame != [self.webView mainFrame]) return;
    
    self.currentUrl = [[[[frame provisionalDataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
    [self retain];

    
}

Comment: Not sure but could it be you need [self.currentURL retain] ? Instead of [self retain]

Comment: That didn't make a difference, I am declaring it in the WebController.h like this:

[at]interface WebController : NSObject <DOMEventListener> {
 
NSString *currentURL;
}
[at]property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentURL;


[at]end

(I'm not allowed to use [at] symbols in comments so yeah.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, or a copy and paste error, but the code you posted is:

```
[@"google.com/search?hl=en&q="; stringByAppendingString:currentURL]]]];
```

It has a stray semicolon in the middle. That shouldn't even compile though.

Comment: Yeah this was a typing error as I was typing on a seperate computer to where the code was. There isn't a stray semicolon in the actual code and I've edited the post. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user1887683, is all the code you're showing in the WebController class? It's not clear from your post which web view is the first one and which is the second one that's in the other view.

Comment: Yes all code is in WebController class and mywebview is the web view on the view.

Comment: @user1887683, if you log self.currentURL  right after you set it (right after self.currentUrl = [[[[frame provisionalDataSource]...) does it log correctly?

Comment: Hmm I tried NSLog(@"TEST",currentURL); afterwards and it just says TEST

I've just tried calling a function which also uses currentURL but is linked from the First Responder and it works correctly and takes the current URL as expected in the program however it is still showing up as TEST without an URL in the console. Have I logged it incorrectly?

Comment: @user1887683, yes, that log is incorrect. If you're trying to append currentURL to TEST then the log should be: NSLog(@"TEST%@",currentURL). You forgot the %@.

Comment: Yes realised shortly after posting, it's been a long night! and yes it is displaying the URL when the app is launching and when I use any of the functions which is accessing currentURL via the first responder however when I call the DisplayInView function the LOG isn't called.

Comment: @user1887683, do you mean you don't get anything logged at all if you put a log in the DisplayInView method?

Comment: Correct the log after (right after self.currentUrl = [[[[frame provisionalDataSource]…)and one in the DisplayInView function both don't show anything when DisplayinView is called.

Comment: @user1887683, then maybe you're never making it past that "return" statement. Put a simple log, like NSLog(@"Got here"), right after that "return" and see if it logs. If it does, then there's something wrong with the way you define currentURL.

Comment: No I don't think it's accessing it at all, interesting I have a data class to access the URLString in another class like this:

DataClass *object = [DataClass getInstance];
object.string=currentURL;

This is located in viewDidLoad.

I changed currentUrl to object.string in DisplayinView and the view didn't load and I got  __NSCFConstantString sytringByAppendingString:]: nil argument, what can cause this?

Comment: @user1887683, what does "No I don't think it's accessing it at all" mean. Did the simple log log anything or not?

Comment: No "I got here" shows up when launching the application and when using any function from the First Responder but doesn't show at all for the DisplayInView function.

Comment: @user1887683, well, then DisplayInView is never being called -- that's your problem.

Comment: No DisplayInView is being called the view is loading in fullscreen as expected, and this url is being loaded into the web view: google.com/search?hl=en&q= however currentURL is not getting appended to the URL string.

Comment: I created an NSLog("test"%@", currentURL); within the DisplayInView function and when calling from First Responder it showed: test http://www.youtube.com however when calling from the WebController it just showed test - how do I make the variable visible from the controller?

Comment: @user1887683, I can't really tell what's going on with your app. It should be working, so I'm guessing something is messed up in the overall structure. If you can email me the app, I can take a look at it, but I can't diagnose it without seeing it.

Comment: I think I still have that one, but I can still look at the code with 4.5 (but maybe not a xib if you have one). My email is rdelmar@comcast.net